# Update table using value from joined table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a value in Table x from Table 2. It looks something like this:

```
update Procedures
set p.providerID=lg.OrgIntValue
FROM [dbo].[Procedures] p
inner join providers pr on p.Provider_Id=pr.PROVIDER_ID 
left join LogCorrection lg on lg.Procedure_Id=p.Procedure_Id
where lg.CorrectionType='Provider Correction'
```

The server says:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
>
> The multi-part identifier "p.providerID" could not be bound.

What is the possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your first line to use the table alias, not the full table name:

```
update p
set p.providerID = lg.OrgIntValue
FROM [dbo].[Procedures] p
--inner join providers pr on p.Provider_Id = pr.PROVIDER_ID 
left join LogCorrection lg on lg.Procedure_Id = p.Procedure_Id
where lg.CorrectionType = 'Provider Correction'
```

Also, why is `providers` joined in your query? It seems to be irrelevant for the filter and for the join to `LogCorrections`.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
set p.Provider_Id = lg.OrgIntValue
```

as you have it as `p.providerID`